# Unable to see Spark Pools in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Cannot see all database in Azure Synapse. I have two other spark pools but i cannot see them in the regular Databases tab.
[image]

Comment: Spark Pools show up in the Manage or Monitor hubs.

Comment: Sql databases and Apache Spark pool are different from each other. An Apache Spark pool provides open-source big data compute capabilities. You can view Apache spark pools from **Monitor >> Apache Spark pool**.

Answer (score 0):

> Data Hubs doesn't shows Apache Spark pool.

**Note:** Data Hub shows only `SQL Databases` and `Lake Database`

[image]

> As you have created two Apache spark pool - you need to check from the `Monitor Hub`.

[image]

Comment: I created a new spark database but it neither shows up in Data Workspace window or the Monitor window. But the database is functional as I can query and update the Data

Comment: Thank you for replying back for my query.

Comment: @S.Thomas As I said above Spark pool doesn't show in Data Hub. Please check monitor tab => Analytics pools => Apache Spark pools

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you were looking for Spark Pool, or Spark data related to those pools,as your question is not clear.

But if you view the spark database, then refresh from top-right corner, and it will appear in the "Lake Database" section.

Previously azure had this way of showing data:
Data -> WorkSpace -> Databases -> SQL Databases, Lakes Database, Spark data.